# Password does not work after setting up google-Authenticator 2fa

Tags: ssh, password, authentication, two-factor-authentication

Hi I have a server at home that I often connect to from my school but I wanted to give it an extra security boost. I followed this tutorial, https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa#1-overview, exactly and signed out after to test it. I've tried putting in my password and now it rejects it. Is there anything I can do to get it to work? I threw in a verbose version of my login attempt if it helps. Thanks

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to 108.11.11.111 [108.11.11.111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 108.11.11.111:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:O1cWLEwyZF0hzc4rB2bNpXmPvolshKlUsQXy2yQwPLc
debug1: Host 'user@108.11.11.111' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\scs137/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
user@108.11.11.111's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
user@108.11.11.111's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
user@108.11.11.11's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@108.11.11.111: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: You will need to authenticate with the correct username and password, then you will need to enter the TOTP key.  If you are getting permission denied, it would be because you're not adding the correct authentication information

Comment: I am having the same issue, after enabling MFA, ssh it will not accept my password.